# How to get lists of indices to unique values efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Is there a built-in method that would help me achieve the following efficiently: given an array, I need a list of arrays, each with indices to a different unique value of the array?

If `f` is the desired function,

```
b = f(a)
```

and

```
u, idxs = unique(a)
```

then

```
b[i] == where(idxs==i)[0]
```

I am aware that `pandas.Series.groupby()` can do this, but it may no be efficient to create a dict when there are over 10^5 unique integers.

Comment: fyi, pandas.Series objects also have a `unique` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have numpy >= 1.9 you can do:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(5, size=10)
>>> a
array([0, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1])
>>> unq, unq_inv, unq_cnt = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
>>> np.split(np.argsort(unq_inv), np.cumsum(unq_cnt[:-1]))
[array([0]), array([9]), array([1, 4, 8]), array([7]), array([2, 3, 5, 6])]
>>> unq
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

In earlier versions, you can get the counts doing an extra:

```
>>> unq_cnt = np.bincount(unq_inv)
```

Also, if you want to make sure that the indices for each value are sorted, I think you will need to use a stable sort, e.g. `np.argsort(unq_inv, kind='mergesort')`

---

Thinking about what you seem to be after, which I think is minimizing calls to an expensive function, I don't think you need to do what you are asking. Say that your function was squaring, you could simply do:

```
>>> unq, unq_inv = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
>>> f_unq = unq**2
>>> f_a = f_unq[unq_inv]
>>> a
array([0, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1])
>>> f_a
array([ 0,  4, 16, 16,  4, 16, 16,  9,  4,  1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo(a):
  I=np.arange(a.shape[0])
  d={}
  while a.shape[0]:
    x = a[0]
    ii = a==x
    d[x] = I[ii]
    a = a[~ii]
    I = I[~ii]
  return d

In [767]: a
Out[767]: array([4, 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3])

In [768]: foo(a)
Out[768]: 
{0: array([3, 4, 8]),
 1: array([6, 7]),
 2: array([5]),
 3: array([2, 9]),
 4: array([0, 1])}
```

Is this the sort of dictionary that you want?

For small `a` this works fine.

An equivalent dictionary building function is:

```
def foo1(a):
    unq = np.unique(a)
    return {i:np.where(a==i)[0] for i in unq}
```

Off hand I don't see how `unq_inv` helps with building the dictionary.

`foo` is about 30% slower than `foo1`.  I was hoping that by reducing the searched array each time a value was counted that I might gain some speed.  But it looks like the extra bookkeeping chews up time.  And the `where` time might not be that sensitive to the length of `a`.

For `a2=np.random.randint(5000,size=100000)` run times are on the order of 2-3 sec.

But `np.random.randint(50000,size=1000000)` takes too long to time (for either version).

---

On further experimentation, a 'dumb' approach using a `collections.defaultdict` is much faster (20x):

```
def food(a):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for i,j in enumerate(a):
        d[j].append(i)
    return d
```

The 'too big' (1000000,) array takes only 1.1 sec;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like:

```
s = argsort(a)
d = diff(a[s])
starts = where(d)[0]
f = [s[starts[i:i+1]] for i in xrange(len(a))]
```

(code not checked)